# How can I add an only read property on a child class? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties

I don´t know how I should do this... "count" Its supossed to be a read only property and I´m not sure about ways to implement that on Inherence , (I can´t know exactly how is the original class coz is a class exercise)

I hope someone can help me on this... Im letting here the code

```html
class SteppedCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, count, step):
        super.__init__(count)
        self.__step = step
        
    @property
    def step(self):
        return self.__step


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example of use (not part of the solution)
    c = SteppedCounter(3)
    print(c.count)
    print(c.step)
    c.add_up()
    print(c.count)
```

This is the error message when I put count in `__init__`

```
TypeError: __ init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'
```

and when I don´t:

```
'SteppedCounter' object has no attribute '_Counter__count'
```

If I add a number in `c = SteppedCounter(3)` just like `c = SteppedCounter(1, 3)` this is the message:

```
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: Try `super().__init__(count)`.

Comment: Don't use `__`-prefixed names until you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should add parentheses to the super() call:

```js
super().__init__(count)
```

you should definitely supply the constructor function with the number of parameters you specified (2 in your case).